# VB-MS Access Validation for textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following vb code setup on one of my forms. I setup a text box where a user can search by a CN number but I am running into an issue. If the user does not enter anything in the textbox and they click search, they are prompted to enter a CN# (Which is what I want). If the user enters a CN #, my query will find that CN# with its detail (Which is what I want). Where my issue lies is if the user types in a incorrect CN#, the query will still pop up, but the query table is empty. I am trying to setup a validation field that restricts what can be typed in or lets the user know that the CN# they typed is incorrect.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    If Nz(txtCN, "") <> "" Then
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery "query_CO_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_2010_2015_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_2016_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    Else
       'If Nz(txtReportDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "NOTICE! Please enter a CN #"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that is not VB.NET code.  There is no `DoCmd`.  You probably want the `access-vba` tag

Comment: @Plutonix fixed, thank you sir!

Comment: You should consider using a ComboBox instead of a textbox. Build it to get it's values from the table containing your valid CN#s. In the ComboBox properties, set 'Limit To List' to Yes.

Comment: @tlemaster thank you for the response. Could you possible guide me or provide me with some sort of source so I can follow?

Comment: @tlemaster I Just setup the combo box and I really like it. How do I add restrictions to the combo box? Such as, user must enter something between 5 to 12 characters,

Comment: This explains better than I could: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-of-choices-by-using-a-list-box-or-combo-box-70abf4a9-0439-4885-9099-b9fa83517603#__toc356995226

Comment: Look at adding a validation rule and validation text to your combo box.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DCOUNT function to test the input text before proceeding with your code.  If the count returns 0 then you can assume there are no records that meet the criteria entered.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    If Nz(txtCN, "") <> "" Then

        If DCount("fldField", "tblTable", "fldField = " & txtCN) > 0 Then
             DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
            'DoCmd.OpenQuery "query_CO_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
            'DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_2010_2015_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
            'DoCmd.OpenQuery "querySearchCN_2016_CE", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        Else
            MsgBox "You have entered an invalid CN #"
        End If
    Else
       'If Nz(txtReportDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "NOTICE! Please enter a CN #"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```